# add new data source in Idea J

Tags: java, sql-server, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I am creating a new `Microsoft SQL Server` data source using `Data Source and Drivers` dialog box in `Intelli J Idea Ultimate 2017.2` IDE

After entering all the required values when I click on `Test Connection` button, it gives `Failed` message with the error as shown below.

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
>         at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
>         at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
>         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:4098)
>         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3160)
>         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$100(SQLServerConnection.java:43)
>         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3123)
>         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7505)
>         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2445)
>         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1981)
>         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1628)
>         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1459)
>         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:773)
>         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1168)
>         at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.impl.RemoteDriverImpl.connect(RemoteDriverImpl.java:27)
>         at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
>         at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:355)
>         at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
>         at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
>         at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:567)
>         at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:800)
>         at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:682)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) (no stack trace).
>       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter

I use `sqljdbc42` driver for connectivity. I have also set `CLASSPATH` environment variable to the location of `sqljdbc42-4.2.jar` file.

[image]

Any idea what could be possibly wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft JDBC Driver requires additional dependency, which is `javax.xml.bind.api`.

This is the maven dependency what you need to add to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You can download the necessary jar file from [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.0/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar) and add it to IntelliJ classpath.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added this dependency to my pom.xml and appended the path to CLASSPATH variable. But still having the same issue. Anything else i could check?

Comment: If you add this dependency to your POM then your application will work fine. If you want to use IntelliJ Database then you need to add the jar to IntelliJ classpath as well.